# react-native-svg - Fill overlapped area of two ellipses

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

We are using [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg) library to draw ellipses having following code

```
<Svg>
      <Ellipse cx={192} cy={190} rx={50} ry={80} stroke={"red"} strokeWidth="2"/>
      <Ellipse cx={250} cy={150} rx={60} ry={30} stroke={"green"} strokeWidth="2"/>
<Svg>
```

Which looks like the image below

[image]

**Our requirement is to fill up the area which gets overlapped by two ellipses.**

If anyone can put some light on it, how can it be achieved using the SVG library for react-native? or if anything else we have will be very helpful

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea is creating a clipPath with one of the ellipses and reusing the other one clipped by the clipPath.

Please observe that I am giving an id to both ellipses so that I can reuse them with use.

```html
<svg fill="none" viewBox="140 101 170 170" width="200">
  
      <ellipse cx="192" cy="190" rx="50" ry="80" stroke="red"
         stroke-width="2" id="a"/>
      <ellipse cx="250" cy="150" rx="60" ry="30" stroke="green" 
        stroke-wdth="2" id="b"/>
  
  <use xlink:href="#a" clip-path="url(#cp)" fill="gold"/>
  
  <clipPath id="cp">
    <use xlink:href="#b"/>
  </clipPath>
  
<svg>
```